# Everytime I check the user's input from a jtextfield window, the result is only printed on my graphic window when I move the whole graphics window

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

So I am making a jeopardy game and there is a jtextfield where the user inputs their answer. When they click the submit button, their answer is stored in a variable. That variable is taken into the class where the jeopardy board is made and checks the user's input with the answer. But in order for correct or incorrect to appear on my graphics window I have to minimize the graphics window and some how that creates another jtextfield window and then only correct or incorrect is printed out.

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Answer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String s;
    static JTextField textfield;
    static JButton jButton;


     public  void findingAnswer() {

          JFrame jf = new JFrame();
          textfield = new JTextField("", 30);
          jButton = new JButton();
          jButton = new JButton("Click");
          jButton.addActionListener(new Answer());

          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          JLabel jl = new JLabel("Put your answer here");
          jf.setSize(500, 500);
          jf.setVisible(true);
          jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          jf.add(panel);
          panel.add(jl);
          panel.add(textfield);
          panel.add(jButton);

     }



       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         s = textfield.getText();

      }

    public String get_s()
     {
         return s;
     }
}
```

// in the class where the jeopardy board is made there is this code:

```
 // answer box
 // calling the previous class to make the window with jtextfield
              an.findingAnswer();
// checks to see if the answer correct
// x is an object from a class where you can get the question and answer
 if (an.get_s().equals(x.getAnswer()))
                 {
                 g.drawString("Correct! +" + y + " points!", 300, 300);
                 if(turns % 2 != 0)
                  {
                      player1 += y;
                      turns ++;
                   }
                  else
                {
                     player2 += y;
                      turns ++;
                   }
            }   
              else
               {
                   g.drawString("Incorrect.\nThe correct answer is: "+   x.getAnswer(), 300, 300);
                 turns ++;
             }
             }
```

The expected result is to get the incorrect and correct statement without having to make more windows or move the screen.

Comment: *"in the class where the jeopardy board is made there is this code:"* We need that class. And better if we have a [mcve]

Comment: Also don't make the window (`JFrame`) visible before adding all you components to it. `jf.setVisible(true);` should be the last line in your constructor. From the current code I can see that you don' need `extends JFrame implements ActionListener `, as you have a class `Answer` that implements `ActionListener` and you're creating an instance of `JFrame jf` in your code, so you're never using the `JFrame` your class is extending. Anyway we need more code to provide more and better answers. Oh and btw, indent your code correctly, this will make it easier for all to follow what the program does.